# JSON data push into Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to push JSON data into a multi-dimensional Array.

I have JSON data like below and already parsed it. But I'm not able to add the data to the array. The JSON below is only for one page. When I flip second page I also get JSON and check whether it exist in the array or not. If not, I want add the data to the array.

**JSON data:**

```
[{
    "8":
    {"hsid":8,"hstype":1,"width":472,"height":141,"xpos":71,"ypos":28,"title":"For example","angle":0,"shape":0,"hotspotbordercolor":null,"hotspotransparency":null,"gotopage":0},
    "10":
    {"hsid":10,"hstype":2,"width":120,"height":114,"xpos":422,"ypos":224,"title":"Link","angle":0,"shape":0,"hotspotbordercolor":null,"hotspotransparency":null,"gotopage":0},
    "11":
    {"hsid":11,"hstype":4,"width":105,"height":77,"xpos":434,"ypos":628,"title":"Go to Page-5","angle":0,"shape":0,"hotspotbordercolor":null,"hotspotransparency":null,"gotopage":5}
}]
```

I want the array in this format:

```
myArray = {
    1: //page no
    {
        8: //id
        {
            "hsid": 8,
            "hstype": 1,
            "width": 472,
            "height": 141
        },
        10: //id
        {
            "hsid": 10,
            "hstype": 2,
            "width": 120,
            "height": 114
        }
    },
    2: //page no
    {
        11: //id
        {
            "hsid": 11,
            "hstype": 4,
            "width": 105,
            "height": 77
        },
        15: //id
        {
            "hsid": 15,
            "hstype": 1,
            "width": 213,
            "height": 207
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please post your code. What exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Your desired result is not an array, it's an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it will be an object tho: http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/MUCg9/
You can push your data into another object then use `var pageExist=$.grep(arrTest,function(e)
                     {
                         return e.hsid=='8';
                     });`
I just put '8' there as a page number for instance but that could be a variable for your page no or something too. 'arrTest' is the other object I pushed data into.

Comment: var pageExist=$.grep(arrTest,function(e)
                     {
                         return e.hsid=='8';
                     });